# optimal agorithm to delete elements from numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, sorting

Hi i need to know if this algorithm can be more efficient. The objetive is delete all the points from 3 arrays, when the radius is bigger than the maximum radius set by the user.

This code search for a position "i" in the ratio array and when the value is bigger than max_rad it remove the element "i" from 3 numpy arrays of Nx1.

```
for i in range(len(rad_vec)-1,-1,-1):
    if rad_vec_temp[i] >= max_rad :
        azim_vec = np.delete(azim_vec, i)
        elev_vec = np.delete(elev_vec, i)
        rad_vec = np.delete(rad_vec, i)
```

I need another way to do the same process but faster than this way.

Comment: Just create a mask based on the condition and index.  Don't iterate, use vectorized methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting which is costly, try selecting like this:

```
#if rad_vec_temp is not an array, first convert it to an array
rad_vec_temp = np.array(rad_vec_temp)
mask = rad_vec_temp<max_rad
azim_vec = azim_vec[mask]
elev_vec = elev_vec[mask]
rad_vec = rad_vec[mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call [`np.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html), the array gets reallocated. That makes the operation expensive. Numpy is all about bulk operations, so here are a few different approaches for you to benchmark. They all hinge on the the fact that you can make a single mask array for the locations to delete:

```
to_delete = (rad_vec_temp >= max_rad)
```

Or alternatively, one to keep:

```
to_keep = (rad_vec_temp < max_rad)
```

1. Use `delete`, but do it once:

   ```
    azim = np.delete(azim, to_delete)
    elev = np.delete(elev, to_delete)
    rad = np.delete(rad, to_delete)
   ```

   Keep in mind that every time you pass in a mask, two passes have to be made over it: one to compute the number of masked elements, and one to apply the mask after allocating the output. This is not efficient since it happens three times.
2. To avoid multiple passes over the mask, you can convert it to indices:

   ```
    indices = np.flatnonzero(to_delete)
    azim = np.delete(azim, indices)
    elev = np.delete(elev, indices)
    rad = np.delete(rad, indices)
   ```
3. You can also use direct indexing with an reverse mask to indicate the locations you want to keep. This is the more common way of doing it, since it is so simple to read and write:

   ```
    azim = azim[to_keep]
    elev = elev[to_keep]
    rad = rad[to_keep]
   ```

   The same issues apply here as to #1.
4. You can use fancy indexing to avoid multiple passes over a mask:

   ```
    indices = np.flatnonzero(to_keep)
    azim = azim[indices]
    elev = elev[indices]
    rad = rad[indices]
   ```

You will have to benchmark these on your specific system. However, I expect that you will find that #1 and #3 are slower than #2 and #4.